# Simple_form can not work with model Inheritance in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

My Route

```
  scope :module => "group" do
    resources :groups do 
      resources :topics
    end
  end
```

My model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Group::Topic < Post
end
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@current_group, @topic], :html => {:id => "post_form", :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| -%> 
end
```

The error message is

> undefined method `group_group_topics_path' for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the case is in `simple_form`. Most likely you have an error in your routes and they should be updated as follows:

```
scope :module => "group" do
  resources :groups do 
    scope :module => :groups do
      resources :topics
    end
  end
end
```

Then you will get `group_group_topics_path` route working. To see all the topics routes type this command in the console: `rake routes | grep 'topics'`.

Comment: Did you open an issue on https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues? What was the answer?

Comment: I do not think it's polymorphic case

Comment: I think it's rails'bug, `[@a, @b]` can not work, but `a_b_path(@a)` can work.